# What is the big picture behind the quotient of a ring by its maximal ideal being a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, intuition, big-picture

A **ring** $(X, +, \times, 0, 1)$ is an algebraic structure such that $(X, +, 0)$ is a commutative group, $(X, \times, 1)$ is a monoid, and $\times$ distributes over $+$.

A **sub-ring** is a subset $Y  \subset X$ such that $(Y, +)$ is a subgroup, and $Y$ is closed under $\times$.

An **ideal** of a ring $X$ is a subset $Z \subset X$ such that $Z$ is closed under $+$, and for any $x \in X$ and $z \in Z$, we have $z \times x \in Z$ and $x \times z \in Z$.

$X$ is itself an ideal of $X$, and it is called the **unit ideal**. An ideal of $X$ which is not the unit ideal is called a **proper ideal**.

A proper ideal $M$ is a **maximal** ideal of $X$ if for any ideal $I$ in $X$ such that $M \subseteq I \subseteq X$, then $I = M$ or $I = X$.

Let $-$ be the inverse of $+$. Define an equivalence relation $\sim$ where $x \sim y$ if and only if $x - y \in I$, where $I$ is an ideal of $X$. Let $X/I$ be the set of equivalence classes of $X$ under $\sim$.

**Fact:** Let $[0], [1]$ be the equivalence classes containing $0$ and $1$ respectively, and $\oplus, \otimes$ the generalizations of $+, \times$ over the equivalence classes in $X/I$. Then, $(X/I, \oplus, \otimes, [0], [1])$ is a ring.

**Fact:** Let $M$ be the maximal ideal of $X$, and let $\sim$ be defined so that $x \sim y$ if and only if $x - y \in M$. Then $X/M$ is a field. That is $(X/M, \oplus, \otimes, [0], [1])$ is such that $(X/M, \oplus, [0])$ and $(X/M \setminus [0], \otimes, [1])$ are groups, and $\otimes$ distributes over $\oplus$.

**Question:** from a big picture/intuition perspective, why might one expect the quotient group of a ring by its maximal ideal to produce a field? What is special about the maximality of the maximal ideal, that $X/M$ is no longer just a ring, but also a field?

Comment: For any ideal $I$ of $X$, there is a bijection between ideals of $X/I$ and ideals of $X$ containing $I$. If $I$ is maximal, then we see that $X/I$ has exactly two ideals, namely the zero ideal and $X/I$ itself. One can check that a (nonzero) ring is a field precisely when this is the case.

Comment: It has no proper nontrivial ideals, which means (in the commutative context) that every element in the quotient has a multiplicative inverse.  By analogy, in the commutative context, moding out a group by a maximal normal subgroup gives you a *cyclic* group, not merely a group.

Comment: You have the wrong definition of maximal ideal. A proper ideal $P$ is maximal in $X$ if for all proper ideals $I$, either $P=I$ or $P\nsubseteq I$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin You need to add to your definition that $M\ne R$, because otherwise $R$ is maximal, which it shouldn't be.

Comment: @Gae.S. Oops; correct, but too late to edit the comment.

Comment: [corrected] You did not define “maximal ideal”, you defined **maximum** ideal; the only rings with an ideal with that property are called “local rings”. An ideal $M\neq R$ of $R$ is maximal if and only if for every ideal $I$ of $R$, if $M\subseteq I\subseteq R$, then either $M=I$ or $I=R$.

Comment: Your definition of “subring” is also not quite correct: $\mathbb{N}$ would be a subring of $\mathbb{Z}$, since it is closed under $+$ and under $\times$, and contains $1$ (and also contains $0$ in my version). You need the subring to be a *subgroup*, and your definition only requires it to be a subsemigroup of the additive structure and a submonoid of the multiplicative structure.

Comment: (in a commutative unital ring) $m$ is maximal means for all $a\not \in m$, $aR+m = R$ ie. $ab+c=1$ for some $b\in R,c\in m$ ie. $ab = 1\in R/m$ ie. $R/m$ is a field.

Comment: It is instructive to compare the above *structural* views with this direct *elementwise* view 
$$\color{#0a0}{x\not\in M}\ {\rm max}\,\Rightarrow\, (x)+M = (1)\,\Rightarrow\,rx + m =1\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{rx = 1}\ {\rm in}\ R/M\qquad $$

therefore in $\,R/M,\,\ \color{#0a0}{x\neq 0}\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{x^{-1}\rm\ exists}$, so $\,R/M\,$ is a field. It is best to master both viewpoints and to learn how to effortlessly transfer between the two.

Comment: @BillDubuque you should write an answer :D

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I fixed the definition of sub-ring and maximal ideal. Is it good now?

Comment: @user89: Why do you not say a subring is a subgroup? You say it for ideals, *where you don’t need to* (for ideals, closure under addition *is* sufficient, because if $x\in I$, then $(-1)x\in I$ (where $-1$ is the additive inverse of $1$), and then one can verify that $(-1)x$ is the additive inverse of $x$. Why are you so intent on being coy about subrings?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I am following Wikipedia, and those are the definitions given in Wikipedia?

Comment: @user89: Are you asking, or telling me? Note that you mention $-$ in your definition of subring, but don’t define it until four paragraphs later. If you insist on trying to be complete, then I would still suggest that your definition of subring is unnecessarily sparse, and your definition of ideal is unnecessarily detailed. Subring should be “a subgroup that is closed under multiplication and contains $1$”, and ideal should be “subset that is closed under addition and absorbs multiplication **on both sides**“ (your current definition is for left ideals only, absent commutativity of $\times$).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin ah okay, thanks.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Does $0$ have to be in every ideal? I am wondering if that's why Wikipedia defines ideals as being closed under subtraction?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin  (sorry, would have updated last comment, but apparently I got to it too late; this is an addition to that one) See WolframMathWorld's definition: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ideal.html ($I$ is a subgroup under $+$ of $R$)?

Comment: @user89: Assuming nonempty, yes: if $x\in I$, then $0=0x\in I$. So you need nonemptiness if you don’t specify subgroup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(*Caveat*: Groups and rings are somewhat special, in that we can “code” quotients via “substructures with something extra”; for more general algebraic objects, such as monoids or semigroups, you need congruences. That said, I will cast my answer in terms of groups and rings.)

Consider quotients in general; the idea of a quotient/homomorphic image is that you can try to study aspects of your object via a quotient, which is (hopefully) simpler than your initial object. Homomorphic images are also important ways of studying an algebraic structure.

The objects for which this doesn’t work are the “simple objects”: objects whose only homomorphic images are the trivial object (everything is identified) and the object itself (the quotient doesn’t do anything). Understanding simple objects is important and interesting, in its own right, of course.

Now look at groups: you have abelian groups and you have nonabelian groups. For abelian groups, every subgroup yields a quotient, so to be an abelian simple group you must have no proper nontrivial subgroups. Those groups have a very basic structure: they must be cyclic of prime order. By contrast, the *nonabelian* simple groups are much more complicated, because while they can have no proper nontrivial *normal* subgroup, they can have lots of subgroups. The study of nonabelian simple groups turns out to be much more complicated, as witnessed by the length of time and the length of paper needed to classify them.

Now let’s look at rings; the role of normal subgroups is played by two-sided ideals. Again, we have two types of rings: commutative and noncommutative.

A commutative ring is going to be simple if and only if it has *no* proper nontrivial ideals. This forces no proper one-sided ideals. What does that tell us about the structure?

Given any ring $R$ and any element $a$, the set $aR=\{ar\mid r\in R\}$ forms a right ideal. If $a\neq 0$, and $R$ has a unity, then if $R$ has no proper one-sided ideals this means that $aR=R$, and in particular that $a$ has a right inverse, since $1\in aR$. Symmetrically, $Ra$ is a left ideal, and so $a$ has a left inverse; thus, in a simple commutative ring, every nonzero element must have an inverse. That is, we must be in a field.

This observation is akin to the observation that in a simple abelian group, we must be in a cyclic group of prime order.

And just as in groups, if you drop commutativity then you end up with a lot more simple rings: for example, the ring of $n\times n$ matrices of a field is simple, even though it has one-sided ideals. While a commutative ring with no proper ideals must be a field, a ring with no proper nontrivial ideals need not be a division ring. (However, a ring with no proper nontrivial one-sided ideals *must* be a division ring, by the same argument as given above for commutativity).

So, for abelian groups, maximal subgroups must have prime index, by the isomorphism theorem: $A/M$ has no proper nontrivial subgroups, so it must be cyclic of prime order, hence $[A:M]$ is prime. For commutative rings, maximal ideals satisfy that $R/M$ has no proper nontrivial ideals, and therefore that $R/M$ is a field (because those are the only simple commutative rings with unity).

Comment: So in general, quotienting by a maximal object gives us a simple object, and the simple commutative rings are fields since if there is an element with no inverse, we can always identify it with zero.

Comment: @JackM I would instead say that if there is an element with no inverse, then "all multiples of that element" is a nontrivial proper ideal.